# Azure Windows Web app with php mysql pdo

Tags: php, mysql, azure, pdo, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to connect to a MySQL for Azure database from a Laravel application. I receive the following error:

```
In PDOConnection.php line 50:
could not find driver
```

I searched for this and found that the PHP installed, doesn't support MySQL PDO. I searched a lot and found out, that the current Web App, does have the `php_pdo_mysql.dll`.

Based on the following [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations), I created the `extensions.ini` file and added the following line:

```
extension=D:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

When I check the phpinfo, I can see that my `extensions.ini` file is used by php correctly as it was described in the documentation, but at the PDO drivers section, I cannot see the MySQL.

Comment: Please let me know if you found the solution.

Comment: No, for this one I didn’t. I started to use container based web apps. I deployed a docker image, that one worked.